# Python Dataframe of array of one column need to expand in multiple rows

Tags: python, json, dataframe

This is my input Data frame , df=

```
  projectName  | Project Status  |   Data
0       ABC    |     completed   | [5ea2b44c7509725686864def,5ea2b8607509725686864f07,5ea2c3b67509725686865229]
```

OUTPUT I need as df=

```
  projectName  | Project Status  |   Data
0       ABC    |   completed     |   5ea2b44c7509725686864def
1       ABC    |     completed   |   5ea2b8607509725686864f07 
2       ABC    |     completed   |   5ea2c3b67509725686865229
```

Comment: Assuming Data is already a list, you can user df.explode('Data')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very primal solution:

```
d = {'projectName': ["ABC"], "Project Status":["completed"], "Data":["5ea2b44c7509725686864def, 5ea2b8607509725686864f07, 5ea2c3b67509725686865229"]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
tmp = ''.join(data['Data']).split(',')
first = d["projectName"]*len(tmp)
second = d["Project Status"]*len(tmp)
d = {'projectName': first, "Project Status":second, "Data":tmp}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```